# What's the array value?

Tags: arrays

Homework question:

> Given the array double x[3], what is the “value” of x? Provide a
>   possible value. Given the value of v of the previous point, what is
>   the address of x[0], x[1] and x[2].

Personal considerations:

In my opinion the value of an array is its collection of items. Eg.

> double x[3] = {8, 9, 88};

but the question would make me think that 'value' is meant the machine starting address of the array (array's base address of the memory block).

My reasoning is that correct? What would be the answer that you would give you?

Comment: I'd say here, value is referring to an address.

Comment: This feels like a homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your reasoning is not correct. The value of `x` is simply an address- the address of the first element in the array. As for what are the addresses of `x[0]`, `x[1]` and `x[2]` they are respectively `x+0`(or simply `x`), `x + sizeof(double)` and `x + sizeof(double) * 2`.

EDIT: as Joachim Isaksson pointed out in fact there are some differences between x and a bare pointer to double. For instance `sizeof(x)` is the size of a single double times the number of elements in `x`.

Comment: Well... `double x[3]` gives `sizeof(x)` as 24, not 4 or 8 as a pointer would normally do. That would imply that the value x contains is 24 bytes in size.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I am not sure what you are saying. I mean I am never using `sizeof(x)`.

Comment: `double *y; double x[3]; std::cout << sizeof(x) << " - " << sizeof(y) << std::endl;` gives `24 - 8` on my machine. If the value of `x` is a pointer, wouldn't the size of `x` be the same as the size of `y`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I got you sorry. You are referring to the first statement that x is simply a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

x on its own is an lvalue for an array containing three doubles at a certain memory address. That's it.

Now there are many situations where such a value will be converted to a "pointer to double" pointing to the first element of that array, but there are other situations where this doesn't happen: When the array is the operand of the sizeof, & (address) or _AlignOf operator.

So if someone says "the value of x is simply an address", that is wrong because sizeof (x) is not the size of an address, but three times the size of a double.